# Charts, spheres and determinants

Tags: differential-geometry, derivatives, determinant

Here are some things I don't understand, I would be very grateful for any help!

1. I am trying to find a chart on the unit sphere that preserves area. The most natural map that springs to my mind is taking the inverse of $\phi(x,y)=(\sin x\cos y, \sin x\sin y, \cos x)$. But the first fundamental form of this map is $EG-F^2=\sin ^2 x$, so presumably the inverse map has $E'G'-F'^2={1\over \sin^2 x}$. So it doesn't preserve area? What is a chart that does?
2. Since the unit sphere cannot be fully represented by one chart, I will need another one, which I believe we can just take the same map but change the domain so that we exclude a disjoint  half great circle? I want the transition functions relating the charts to have derivative s with determinant 1 but I don't understand what that means. Presumably it implies area- and orientation- preservation.

I am very sorry about the original version of my question.

Comment: $\theta$ is not a chart of the unit sphere; because $(\cos y)^2+(\sin y)^2+(\cos x)^2 \neq 1$ in general.

Comment: @Paul: I have added a line  that the ***inverses*** of these maps are (hopefully now) the charts of the unit sphere?

Comment: Sorry about the edits. The question should be right now.

Comment: What maps?  What functions?  Which spaces are you trying to relate?  Do you mean atlas charts $\phi,\psi:M\to \mathbb{R}^n$ for a smooth manifold $M$?

Comment: Since you haven't given any context, I assume you're talking about smooth functions like $f:M\rightarrow N$ between smooth manifolds.  A smooth function induces a bundle map between the tangent bundles $Df:TM\rightarrow TN$: at each point $p\in M$, $Df_p:T_p M\rightarrow T_{f(p)} N$ is a linear map between vector spaces, so it makes sense to talk about the determinant.  Note that $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a smooth manifold, so these concepts also make sense there.

Comment: @Neal: Sorry about the confusion. I have edited the question.

Comment: @you: Thank you for your comment! I am not familiar with "bundles" though... I have edited the question, hopefully the added context would allow something more elementary?

Comment: Russel, welcome to Math.SE !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) To find a chart on the unit sphere that preserves area, you might try checking out [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_projection#Equal-area) and going from there.  I believe cartographers have been worrying about this for centuries!

To produce one yourself, write down the volume form on $\mathbb{S}^2$ and make sure that it is preserved under your chart $\phi$.

(2) You are exactly correct; a matrix with determinant $1$ preserves both area and orientation.  Saying that the change-of-coordinate map "has determinant $1$" is exactly saying that it preserves both infinitesimal area and orientation. (More precisely, it preserves the volume form on each tangent space.)

To produce such a chart, since I believe you are operating on the round sphere (i.e., the metric induced from $\mathbb{S}^2\hookrightarrow\mathbb{R}^3$, you could simply precompose your chart with an appropriate rotation of the sphere.  For instance, if your chart $\phi_n$ is well-defined everywhere but the south pole, define a chart about the south pole by first rotating $180$ degrees about an axis through the equator, then using $\phi_n$.

More generally, if $\phi$ is an area-preserving chart of a Riemannian manifold $M$ and $f$ is an isometry of $M$, $\phi\circ f$ is also an area-preserving chart.  To see that the change-of-coordinate map has determinant $1$, just note that $\det d(\phi f\phi^{-1}) = \det d\phi \det df (\det d\phi)^{-1} = 1$ by the chain rule and properties of determinants, and because $f$ is an isometry (hence is, in particular, volume-preserving).

Answer (score 1):

Introduce polar coordinates $(\theta,\phi)$ around the north pole $(\theta=0)$ and polar coordinates $(\rho,\phi)$ in the $(\xi,\eta)$-plane. You want a map $$(\theta,\phi)\mapsto\bigl(\rho(\theta),\phi\bigr) \qquad(\theta\geq0)$$ that preserves areas. Looking at an infinitesimal annulus of width $d\theta$ at geographic latitude $\theta$ and its image in the $(\xi,\eta)$-plane we should have
$$2\pi \sin\theta\ d\theta = 2\pi \rho(\theta)d\rho\ .$$
This is a differential equation for the unknown function $\theta\mapsto\rho(\theta)$, and as $\rho(0)=0$ we obtain
$$\rho(\theta)=2\sin{\theta\over2}\ .$$
This is the basic formula that guarantees preserving of area. Now you have to convert this somehow to the cartesian coordinates $(\xi,\eta)$ in the parameter plane and to the  coordinates $(x,y,z)$ describing points of $S^2$.